# What are some good books that explain the strategic ideas behind the Nimzo-Indian Defence, from Black's perspective?

Tags: opening, books, recommendations, nimzo-indian

I'm looking for a book, which does not have to be modern at all, that comprehensively explains the strategic ideas of the Nimzo-Indian Defence from Black's perspective.

Comment: There has to be many considering how mainstream nimzo is

Comment: The Nimzo is a very non-forcing opening with a myriad of possible variations and positional decisions. I doubt that any single book exists that is truly "comprehensive". For example, you can play the Nimzo with ..d5 or ..c5 first; you can play a hybrid between the Nimzo and the Dutch (with ..f5). Most books provide analysis for a repertoire, and therefore only discuss the ideas of some chosen lines. There are many books on the Nimzo, that hardly share any lines after a few moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I play the Nimzo. There is no doubt that Anatoly Karpov is one of the best, if not the best, strategic players of all times.. This link is a good point to start. You will find many analyzed games of Anatoly Karpov in the Nimzo.

In the same website, you will find analyzed games of Petrosian, Capablanca, Kramink, Alekhine, Botvinnik, Smyslov, etc. Almost all the world chess champions played the Nimzo. In the same website, you can find analyzed games of Nimzowitch, who was not a world chess champion, but invented the opening.

Here is the link: https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?pid=20719&playercomp=black&opening=E20-E59&title=Anatoly%20Karpov%20playing%20the%20Nimzo%20Indian%20as%20Black